# How to combine two dataframes and naturally sort on a column of mixed alphanumeric types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, indexing

I have [a dataframe `df1`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15OU7SwaxqW4vds3E2uN-exPiXOQg2bMJmrGcxIYalaI/edit?usp=sharing):

```py
   QID Questions    B Answer1 Answer2 Answer3  F  G  H  I  J
0    3         a  4.0       a       a       a  a  e  g  i  l
1    4         b  5.0       b       b       b  a  r  h  m  p
2    5         d  5.0     NaN       e       d  b  u  e  i  z
3    6         e  5.0       d       h       r  b  c  z  i  3
```

And [another one, `new_dataframe`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-fecLRvgTpAZ9UmPk_lQ4gFnTFIvoA6p/view?usp=sharing) that I would like to add between the lines of `df_1`.

```py
   QID Questions    B Answer1 Answer2 Answer3  F  G  H  I  J
2  4_1         z  5.0       b       k       b  a  r  h  m  p
3  4_2         w  4.0       b       k       b  c  r  h  m  p
```

Indeed, I would like to obtain:

```py
   QID Questions    B Answer1 Answer2 Answer3  F  G  H  I  J
0    3         a  4.0       a       a       a  a  e  g  i  l
1    4         b  5.0       b       b       b  a  r  h  m  p
2  4_1         z  5.0       b       k       b  a  r  h  m  p
3  4_2         w  4.0       b       k       b  c  r  h  m  p
4    5         d  5.0     NaN       e       d  b  u  e  i  z
5    6         e  5.0       d       h       r  b  c  z  i  3
```

So I want to integrate the lines of the second data frame `new_dataframe` whose QID is composed of a digit and a sub-digit, following the lines of `df1`. For example the lines in `new_dataframe` which QID is `4_1`, `4_2` ... should be integrated after `4`.

Until now I tried the following:

```
# Now I would like to join this new dataframe with dataframe_1, respecting the index, sort it and so on.
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    qid = row['QID']
    # test if there is such a QID in new_dataframe
    repeated_question = new_dataframe[new_dataframe['QID'].split("_")[0] == qid]
    # insert them
```

## Update

I tried Trenton McKinney's updated answer with the actual data and got an exception:

```
from natsort import index_natsorted as ins
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# read the files
df1 = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/Auspex/QuestionBank_06082020_QGrid_and_CINT.csv", dtype={'QID': str}, low_memory=False)
df1.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

df2 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Auspex/new_df.csv', dtype={'QID': str})
df2.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

# concat them
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# sort the values using the key parameter in sort_values
df.sort_values(by='QID', key=lambda col: np.argsort(ins(col))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-d9f848d1f6bf> in <module>()
     14 
     15 # sort the values using the key parameter in sort_values
---> 16 df.sort_values(by='QID', key=lambda col: np.argsort(ins(col))).reset_index(drop=True)

TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Updated: Using the datafiles and `natsort`

- With the mixed data types of containing strings and numbers, the values will not be sorted in numerical order, but related values will be together.

  - `100` will be with `100_A` for example.
- In order to resolve this issue, use [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/), available for `pip` or `conda` installation.
- This will use the `key` parameter of `.sort_values`

```py
from natsort import index_natsorted as ins
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# read the files
df1 = pd.read_csv('data/QuestionBank_06082020_QGrid_and_CINT - QuestionBank_06082020_QGrid_and_CINT.csv', dtype={'QID': str}, low_memory=False)
df1.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

df2 = pd.read_csv('data/new_df.csv', dtype={'QID': str})
df2.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)

# concat them
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# sort the values using the key parameter in sort_values
df.sort_values(by='QID', key=lambda col: np.argsort(ins(col))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

### Sample result

```py
# display(df.iloc[:60, :1])

     QID
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4      0
5     0R
6      1
7      2
8      4
9      5
10    5R
11     6
12     7
13     8
14     9
15    10
16    11
17    12
18    13
19    14
20    15
21    16
22    17
23    18
24    19
25    20
26  20_1
27  20_2
28  20_3
29  20_4
30  20_5
31  20_6
32  20_7
33    21
34    22
35    23
36    24
37   24R
38    25
39    26
40    27
41    28
42    29
43    30
44    31
45    32
46    33
47    34
48    35
49    36
50  36_1
51  36_2
52  36_3
53  36_4
54  36_5
55  36_6
56  36_7
57  36_8
58  36_9
59    37
```

### Original Answer: Using test data

- [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the dataframes
- `df1.QID` may be a column of `int` based on the example, and `df2.QID` will be `str` type.

  - When the DataFrames are combined, the `'QID'` column will need to be converted to `str` type with [`.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), as it will be mixed type when created, and [`.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) will not work.

    - `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` will result if the `'QID'` column has mixed types.

```py
# concat the dataframes
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# convert the column to strings
df.QID = df.QID.astype(str)

# sort and reset
df = df.sort_values('QID').reset_index(drop=True)

# display(df)
   QID Questions    B Answer1 Answer2 Answer3  F  G  H  I  J
0    3         a  4.0       a       a       a  a  e  g  i  l
1    4         b  5.0       b       b       b  a  r  h  m  p
2  4_1         z  5.0       b       k       b  a  r  h  m  p
3  4_2         w  4.0       b       k       b  c  r  h  m  p
4    5         d  5.0     NaN       e       d  b  u  e  i  z
5    6         e  5.0       d       h       r  b  c  z  i  3
```

Comment: Many thanks! I tried it but got a TypeError exception `sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'`I thought this exception would have only been fired if it were a pandas Series ? I've updated my question with my attempt

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica you need to update pandas. Key is only available since version 1.1.0